# Implementation of strnicmp in c

Tags: c, string, implementation

Iam trying to understand the Implementation of strnicmp  from linux source code.
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/string.c

I just tried to implement it without extra variable c1 and c2 and added some condition in while.

```
int StrNiCmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t len)
{
    if(!len)
    return 0;

    do {
            if(!(*s1) || !(*s2))
            break;

            if(*s1 == *s2)
            continue;

            if(ToLower(*s1) != (ToLower(*s2)))
            break;
    } while(len-- && *s1++ && *s2++) ;

    return (int)(*s1) - (int)(*s2);

}
```

So my query is that above implementation has any potentially bug in this.
i have checked with some basic test cases to verify function it worked well. Is this good idea to go without any extra variable

Comment: This question is better suited to [codereview.se].

Comment: It's not correct, because your return value is not derived from a case-insensitive comparison. `StrNiCmp("furs","FUSS",4) != StrNiCmp("FURS","fuss",4)`

Comment: @paddy You are  correct need to return a case-insensitive value ...thank you

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: Note that this is exactly why those local variables are kept: they avoid redundant calls to `tolower`.

Comment: while(len-- && *s1++ && *s2++)  is this ok to add extra check condition in while loop

Comment: is this ok to use return (int)(ToLower(*s1)) - (int)(ToLower(*s2));  to avoid  case-insensitive comparison .... though this might be overhead.

Comment: It's redundant.  The string terminator test is handled in the body of the loop.  And yes, it's overhead to call `ToLower` again on values that you already called `ToLower` on.  What is wrong with using the version written by Linus himself?  Which even the comments in the code indicate is not that great?  And it's still better than this.

Comment: @paddy thank you for your input ...there is nothing wrong in Linux source code iam trying to understand it in better

Comment: The casting here `(int)(*s1) - (int)(*s2);` is not needed as if of lower rank then `int` the operands to arithmetic operators are promote to  `int` anyways.

Comment: Where is `ToLower()` defined? Does it modify the parameter that is passed? I only find `tolower()` which does not change the character passed as parameter. If you do not store the result of `tolower`, you need to call it again when you calculate return value.  The condition of the loop is not correct. You compare 1 character too much.

Answer (score 1):

This saves 1 register compared to the official implementation. It's off the top of my head and only tested with some simple cases.

```
int StrNiCmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t len)
{
    int diff = 0;
    while (!diff && len-- && *s1 && *s2) {
        if (*s1 != *s2)
            diff = (int)ToLower(*s1) - (int)ToLower(*s2);
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    return diff;
}
```

This one might be slightly more efficient:

```
int StrNiCmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t len)
{
    int diff = 0;
    while (len-- && *s1 && *s2) {
        if (*s1 != *s2)
            if (diff = (int)ToLower(*s1) - (int)ToLower(*s2))
                break;
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    return diff;
}
```

Comment: `if (*s1 != *s2)
            if (diff = (int)ToLower(*s1) - (int)ToLower(*s2))` No that's not right. Wouldn't your function return `0` for `strnicmp("Abc", "ade")`? You have to compare `tolower` characters, `if (tolower(*s1) != tolower(*s2))`.

Comment: No. The first test, comparing the original values (regardless of case) is for speed. That is an extremely fast test and will prevent calling ToLower for both characters if they are identical. Only if they are not identical (IE 'A' != 'a') are they converted to lowercase for the case insensitive test.

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct, because your return value is not derived from a case-insensitive comparison. `StrNiCmp("furs","FUSS",4) != StrNiCmp("FURS","fuss",4)`

> while(len-- && *s1++ && *s2++) is this ok to add extra check condition in while loop

It's redundant. The string terminator test is handled in the body of the loop.

> is this ok to use return (int)(ToLower(*s1)) - (int)(ToLower(*s2)); to avoid case-insensitive comparison .... though this might be overhead.

… yes, it's overhead to call `ToLower` again on values that you already called `ToLower` on.
                    – paddy